# Molecular addon is baking / simulating more frames than i asked it to

Tags: particles, add-on

I just installed the molecular addon to use for a particle system using metaballs. When i click "start molecular simulation" it begins baking. However, i want it to bake from frames 800 - 1200, but it bakes from 800 - 4500. I am using blender 3.5

Comment: this is "normal" - the shown frames which it is baken are wrong, but it bakes the right frames. Just ignore that and bake it - it works.

Comment: I see. However, this issue is that it is taking up so much extra time. Is there no fix? Thank you for your response.

Comment: it doesn't really bake more frames. You can see that, if you play the animation afterwards. It is just a "wrong" display.